I can't add a virtual button
I want to create a simple augmented reality application with Vuforia on Unity. However, I can't add a virtual button to the image target. I have also included a screenshot below. How can I add it? I have updated the Unity version to the latest, but it still doesn't work.
Can you describe the steps required?


Virtual Buttons are a deprecated and now removed feature since Vuforia Engine 10.22. See the release notes https://developer.vuforia.com/library/release-notes/vuforia-engine-release-notes . If you really want to use this feature you will have to find an older version of the Engine SDK but it is not a recommendable practice.
